# How can I add a section with a different background color?

Tags: css, block-editor, theme-twenty-twenty-two

I've installed Wordpress on my server and I'm attempting to implement the design I've mocked up in Figma. It's a pretty simple design but it employs different colored sections to break up the content of the page by topic.

I was hoping that I could add a block that is a "section" or "area" but I'm not seeing anything like that.

Comment: Are you using gutenberg?  Try "group" as your block style.

Comment: @rudtek thanks! that's closer. Is there a way to make the group stretch without any margin to the edges of the viewport?

Comment: for context: https://nationalparksatoz.com/

Comment: oh, my header got messed up... lol. I'll fix it. but look past the default bird if it's still there

Comment: added a full answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using gutenberg choose a "group" block.  You'll be able to set the background to any color you would like.  If you want the group to span the width of the page you'll need to set the alignment to "full-width".  When you hover over the block itself you'll get a toolbar pop up.  Make sure you're on the "group" block!  Then look for the alignment icon and choose full width.

If you're looking to put content into the group and want it contained, add whichever block you need into the Group.

Comment: I'm trying this now 

Comment: wow. It's crazy (and disappointing) that wordpress put some of the settings on a pop-up and not with the "settings" in the side panel. Hopefully, they will fix that. Thank you!

Comment: Different plugins to put it to the side, but Gutenberg hasn't "pressed" that "issue." I'll walk myself out.

Comment: I have an "ink"ling of what you did there.